# update jdbcTemplate not firing trigger

Tags: java, oracle, triggers, jdbctemplate

i have update statement when i run it in code by jdbcTemplate ,, update trigger not fired .

```
jdbcTemplate.update(updateQueryBuilder.toString(), params.toArray());
```

trigger

```
create or replace TRIGGER it_update after  update
   ON im_customer_uda
   FOR EACH ROW
begin
 if :old.Status <> :new.Status then insert into log_table(logtxt,ticket_id,updated_date,recid) values ('User '|| :old.updated_by ||' changed Status from ' || :old.Status||' to '|| :new.Status,:old.im_customer_uda_id,sysdate,log_table_s.nextval); end if;
 if :old.urgency <> :new.urgency then insert into log_table(logtxt,ticket_id,updated_date,recid) values ('User '|| :old.updated_by ||' changed urgency from ' || :old.urgency||' to '|| :new.urgency,:old.im_customer_uda_id,sysdate,log_table_s.nextval); end if;
 if :old.impact <> :new.impact then insert into log_table(logtxt,ticket_id,updated_date,recid) values ('User '|| :old.updated_by ||' changed impact from ' || :old.impact||' to '|| :new.impact,:old.im_customer_uda_id,sysdate,log_table_s.nextval); end if;
 if :old.ttpriority <> :new.ttpriority then insert into log_table(logtxt,ticket_id,updated_date,recid) values ('User '|| :old.updated_by ||' changed ttpriority from ' || :old.ttpriority||' to '|| :new.ttpriority,:old.im_customer_uda_id,sysdate,log_table_s.nextval); end if;
 if :old.reporteddate <> :new.reporteddate then insert into log_table(logtxt,ticket_id,updated_date,recid) values ('User '|| :old.updated_by ||' changed reporteddate from ' || :old.reporteddate||' to '|| :new.reporteddate,:old.im_customer_uda_id,sysdate,log_table_s.nextval); end if;
 if :old.respondeddate <> :new.respondeddate then insert into log_table(logtxt,ticket_id,updated_date,recid) values ('User '|| :old.updated_by ||' changed respondeddate from ' || :old.respondeddate||' to '|| :new.respondeddate,:old.im_customer_uda_id,sysdate,log_table_s.nextval); end if;
 if :old.ttowner <> :new.ttowner then insert into log_table(logtxt,ticket_id,updated_date,recid) values ('User '|| :old.updated_by ||' changed ttowner from ' || :old.ttowner||' to '|| :new.ttowner,:old.im_customer_uda_id,sysdate,log_table_s.nextval); end if;
 if :old.vendorgroup <> :new.vendorgroup then insert into log_table(logtxt,ticket_id,updated_date,recid) values ('User '|| :old.updated_by ||' changed vendorgroup from ' || :old.vendorgroup||' to '|| :new.vendorgroup,:old.im_customer_uda_id,sysdate,log_table_s.nextval); end if;
 if :old.description <> :new.description then insert into log_table(logtxt,ticket_id,updated_date,recid) values ('User '|| :old.updated_by ||' changed description from ' || :old.description||' to '|| :new.description,:old.im_customer_uda_id,sysdate,log_table_s.nextval); end if;
 if :old.actualfaulttime <> :new.actualfaulttime then insert into log_table(logtxt,ticket_id,updated_date,recid) values ('User '|| :old.updated_by ||' changed actualfaulttime from ' || :old.actualfaulttime||' to '|| :new.actualfaulttime,:old.im_customer_uda_id,sysdate,log_table_s.nextval); end if;
 if :old.da <> :new.da then insert into log_table(logtxt,ticket_id,updated_date,recid) values ('User '|| :old.updated_by ||' changed da from ' || :old.da||' to '|| :new.da,:old.im_customer_uda_id,sysdate,log_table_s.nextval); end if;
 if :old.actualresolutiontime <> :new.actualresolutiontime then insert into log_table(logtxt,ticket_id,updated_date,recid) values ('User '|| :old.updated_by ||' changed actualresolutiontime from ' || :old.actualresolutiontime||' to '|| :new.actualresolutiontime,:old.im_customer_uda_id,sysdate,log_table_s.nextval); end if;
 if :old.preventiveaction <> :new.preventiveaction then insert into log_table(logtxt,ticket_id,updated_date,recid) values ('User '|| :old.updated_by ||' changed preventiveaction from ' || :old.preventiveaction||' to '|| :new.preventiveaction,:old.im_customer_uda_id,sysdate,log_table_s.nextval); end if;
 if :old.preventiveactiondue <> :new.preventiveactiondue then insert into log_table(logtxt,ticket_id,updated_date,recid) values ('User '|| :old.updated_by ||' changed preventiveactiondue from ' || :old.preventiveactiondue||' to '|| :new.preventiveactiondue,:old.im_customer_uda_id,sysdate,log_table_s.nextval); end if;
 if :old.drivetest <> :new.drivetest then insert into log_table(logtxt,ticket_id,updated_date,recid) values ('User '|| :old.updated_by ||' changed drivetest from ' || :old.drivetest||' to '|| :new.drivetest,:old.im_customer_uda_id,sysdate,log_table_s.nextval); end if;
 if :old.assetid <> :new.assetid then insert into log_table(logtxt,ticket_id,updated_date,recid) values ('User '|| :old.updated_by ||' changed assetid from ' || :old.assetid||' to '|| :new.assetid,:old.im_customer_uda_id,sysdate,log_table_s.nextval); end if;
 end;
```

when i make an update statement from sqlDeveloper trigger is fired successfully . can any one help me

Comment: Maybe a transaction timing issue?  For instance if the update you're looking at is part of a transaction that hasn't completed yet, or is rolled back by a subsequent error (or one part of the trigger itself *causes* the rollback, and they all get undone)

Comment: I would change the condition because it doesn't consider null values, I would use `if :old.Status <> :new.Status  OR :old.Status IS NULL AND :new.Status IS NOT NULL  OR  :old.Status IS NOT NULL AND :new.Status IS NULL then ...`

Comment: @Gus i think it's not transaction issue , because the update statement is completed and the updated columns is reflected

Comment: @krokodilko you are right ,thanks it's worked